# JSF 2.0 set attribute bean when event change

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, richfaces

I'm using richfaces and trying call method in bean when event component is fired. I want call to directly the "set" attribute.

xhtml:

```
    h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{!mbean.myFlag}" immediate="true">
        <a4j:ajax event="click" immediate="true"></a4j:ajax>
    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

Mbean:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@ManagedBean(name = "mbean")
@ViewScoped
public class MyMbean implements Serializable {

private Boolean myFlag;   
...

/** @see #myFlag*/
public Boolean getMyFlag() {
    return flagCartaEmitida;
}

/** @see #myFlag*/
public void setMyFlag(Boolean myFlag) {
    this.myFlag= myFlag;
}

...
```

When click in checkbox get an error:

```
javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException: org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwarePropertyNotWritableException: javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: Illegal Syntax for Set Operation
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
value="#{!mbean.myFlag}"
```

You can't use this EL syntax for a "set" operation. You should remove the exclamation `!` and inverse the value in the model itself so that you can use the proper EL syntax:

```
value="#{mbean.notMyFlag}"
```

Answer (score -1):

I think a getter for a boolean has to be declared as isMyFlag, not getMyFlag.

Comment: OP is using `Boolean`, not `boolean`. So using `isXxx()` would ultimately fail. Note that *both* prefixes are valid for a `boolean`. See also the Javabeans specification.